# I have registration form to sign in but from admin panel admin can also add new user with that same form. how can check if form submitted by admin?

Tags: php, forms, laravel, laravel-5

i have registration form to register new users, but the same time from admin panel, admin can also register new user with the same form. now the prob is how can i check if form is submitted by admin or not ?

its my user table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('username')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->boolean('active')->default(0);
        $table->boolean('admin')->default(0);
        $table->boolean('banned')->default(0);
        $table->string('avatar')->nullable();
        $table->string('activation_token')->nullable();
        $table->string('remember_token')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and this is my Usercontroller

use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class UserController extends \BaseController implements RemindableInterface {

```
use RemindableTrait;

//Rules required to register the user
public static $rules = array(
    'username' => 'required|unique:users|alpha_dash|between:5,15',
    'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
    'password' => 'required|alpha_dash|between:6,12|confirmed',
    'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required',
);

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 * GET /user/create
 *
 * @param  string $username
 * @param  string $email
 * @param  string $password
 * @param  boolean $active
 * @param  string $activation_token
 * @param  string $filename
 * @param  int $points
 * @return Response
 */
public function create($username, $email, $password, $active = 0, $activation_token = null, $filename = null)
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->username = $username;
    $user->email = $email;
    $user->password = $password;
    $user->active = $active;
    $user->activation_token = $activation_token;
    if ($filename) {
        $user->avatar = $filename;
    }
    $user->save();

    return $user;
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 * GET /user/settings
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function settings()
{
    $user = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->first();
    $data = array('user' => $user);
    return View::make('user.settings', $data);
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 * PUT /user/{id}
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function update($id = null)
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $validator = Validator::make(
        $input,
        array(
            'email' => 'required|email:unique:users',
            'password' => 'alpha_dash|between:6,12|confirmed',
            'username' => 'alpha_dash|between:5,15',
        )
    );

    if ($validator->passes()) {
        if($id == null) {
            $id = $input['user'];
        }
        $user = User::find($id);
        $inputPassword = isset($input['password']) ? $input['password'] : null;
        if (!empty($inputPassword)) {
            $user->password = Hash::make($inputPassword);
        }
        $inputUsername = isset($input['username']) ? $input['username'] : null;
        if (!empty($inputUsername)) {
            $user->username = $inputUsername;
        }
        $inputEmail = isset($input['email']) ? $input['email'] : null;
        if (!empty($inputEmail) && $user->email != $inputEmail) {
            $user->email = $inputEmail;
            if(!$user->admin) {
                $email = $inputEmail;
                $user->active = 0;
                $activation_token = str_random(64);
                $user->activation_token = $activation_token;
                $data = array('username' => $user->username, 'activation_token' => $activation_token);
                Mail::send(
                    'emails.welcome',
                    $data,
                    function ($message) use ($email) {
                        $message->to($email)->subject(Lang::get('words.activation-subject'));
                    }
                );
            }
        }
        $user->save();
        $redirectURL = $user->admin ? 'admin/user' : 'settings';
        return json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Updated', 'url' => $redirectURL));
    }

    return json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => $validator->messages()->all()[0]));
}

public function sendActivation()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    if (!$user->active) {
        $email = $user->email;
        $activation_token = str_random(64);
        $user->activation_token = $activation_token;
        $data = array('username' => $user->username, 'activation_token' => $activation_token);
        Mail::send(
            'emails.welcome',
            $data,
            function ($message) use ($email) {
                $message->to($email)->subject(Lang::get('words.activation-subject'));
            }
        );
        $user->save();
        return Redirect::to('/')->with(array('status' => 'showSuccessToast', 'message' => Lang::get('words.activation-resend')));
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('/')->with(array('status' => 'showErrorToast', 'message' => Lang::get('words.activation-resend')));
    }
}

public function upload($id, $type)
{
    if (!Auth::guest()) {
        $input = Input::all();
        $validator = Validator::make(
            $input,
            array(
                'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,png'
            )
        );
        if ($validator->passes()) {
            $user = User::find($id);
            $mediaDir = 'uploads/' . $type . 's/';

            $oldImgPath =  $mediaDir . $user->$type . '.jpg';

            $name = Custom::slugify('');

            $newImg = Custom::imgUpload($input['image'], $name, $type.'s', false, false);
            $newImg .= '/' . $name;
            $user->$type = $newImg;
            $user->save();
            if (file_exists($oldImgPath)) {
                unlink($oldImgPath);
            }
            return json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => Lang::get('words.profile-updated'), 'img' => $newImg));
        }
        return json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => $validator->messages()->all()[0]));
    } else {
        return json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => Lang::get('words.auth-failed')));
    }
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 * DELETE /user/{id}
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Login the user.
 * POST /login
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function login()
{
    // get login POST data
    $email_login = array(
        'email' => Input::get('email'),
        'password' => Input::get('password'),
    );

    $username_login = array(
        'username' => Input::get('email'),
        'password' => Input::get('password'),
    );

    $remember = Input::get('remember') == 'on' ? true : false;

    if (Auth::attempt($email_login, $remember) || Auth::attempt($username_login, $remember)) {
        if (Auth::user()->banned) {
            Auth::logout();
            return json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => Lang::get('words.you-banned')));
        }
        return json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => Lang::get('words.login-success')));
    } else {
        return json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => Lang::get('words.login-error')));
    }

}

// *********** FACEBOOK OAUTH SIGNIN/SIGNUP ********** //

public function loginWithFacebook()
{
    $settings = Setting::first();
    $code = Input::get('code');

    $fb = OAuth::consumer('Facebook');

    if (!empty($code)) {
        // This was a callback request from facebook, get the token
        $token = $fb->requestAccessToken($code);

        // Send a request with it
        $result = json_decode($fb->request('/me'), true);
        $oauth_userid = $result['id'];
        $oauth_username = $result['name'];
        $oauth_username = Custom::slugify($oauth_username);
        $oauth_email = isset($result['email']) ? $result['email'] : $oauth_username.'@facebook.com';

        //dd($oauth_username);

        if (isset($oauth_userid) && isset($oauth_username)) {
            $fb_auth = OauthUser::where('oauth_uid', $oauth_userid)->where('service', 'facebook')->first();
            if (isset($fb_auth->id)) {
                $user = User::find($fb_auth->user_id);
            } else {
                // Execute Add or Login Oauth User
                $user = User::where('email', $oauth_email)->first();
                if (!isset($user->id)) {
                    $username = $this->createUsernameIfExists($oauth_username);
                    $email = $oauth_email;
                    $password = Hash::make(Custom::slugify('', 12));
                    /*if ($email != $oauth_username.'@facebook.com') {
                        $active = 1;
                    } else {
                        $active = 0;
                    }*/
                    $user = $this->create($username, $email, $password, 1);

                    $new_oauth_user = new OauthUser();
                    $new_oauth_user->user_id = $user->id;
                    $new_oauth_user->service = 'facebook';
                    $new_oauth_user->oauth_uid = $oauth_userid;
                    $new_oauth_user->save();

                } else {
                    // Redirect and send error message that email already exists. Let them know that they can request to reset password if they do not remember
                    return Redirect::to('/')->with(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => Lang::get('words.username-exists')));
                }
            }
            // Redirect to new User Login;
            Auth::login($user, true);
            return Redirect::to('/')->with(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => Lang::get('words.login-success')));
        }

    } else {
        $url = $fb->getAuthorizationUri();
        // return to facebook login url
        return Redirect::to((string)$url);
    }
}

// *********** TWITTER OAUTH SIGNIN/SIGNUP ********** //

public function loginWithTwitter()
{
    $settings = Setting::first();

    // get data from input
    $token = Input::get('oauth_token');
    $verify = Input::get('oauth_verifier');

    // get twitter service
    $tw = OAuth::consumer('Twitter');

    // if code is provided get user data and sign in
    if (!empty($token) && !empty($verify)) {
        // This was a callback request from twitter, get the token
        $token = $tw->requestAccessToken($token, $verify);

        // Send a request with it
        $result = json_decode($tw->request('account/verify_credentials.json'), true);

        $oauth_userid = $result['id'];
        $oauth_username = Custom::slugify($result['screen_name']);
        $oauth_email = $oauth_username.'@twitter.com';

        if (isset($oauth_userid) && isset($oauth_username)) {
            $twitter_auth = OauthUser::where('oauth_uid', $oauth_userid)->where('service', 'twitter')->first();

            if (isset($twitter_auth->id)) {
                $user = User::find($twitter_auth->user_id);
            } else {
                // Execute Add or Login Oauth User
                $user = User::where('email', $oauth_email)->first();
                if (!isset($user->id)) {
                    $username = $this->createUsernameIfExists($oauth_username);
                    $email = $oauth_email;
                    $password = Hash::make(Custom::slugify('', 12));
                    $user = $this->create($username, $email, $password, 1);

                    $new_oauth_user = new OauthUser();
                    $new_oauth_user->user_id = $user->id;
                    $new_oauth_user->service = 'twitter';
                    $new_oauth_user->oauth_uid = $oauth_userid;
                    $new_oauth_user->save();

                } else {
                    // Redirect and send error message that email already exists. Let them know that they can request to reset password if they do not remember
                    return Redirect::to('/')->with(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => Lang::get('words.username-exists')));
                }
            }
            // Redirect to new User Login;
            Auth::login($user, true);
            return Redirect::to('/')->with(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => Lang::get('words.login-success')));

        }
    } else {
        // get request token
        $reqToken = $tw->requestRequestToken();
        // get Authorization Uri sending the request token
        $url = $tw->getAuthorizationUri(array('oauth_token' => $reqToken->getRequestToken()));

        //dd($url);
        return Redirect::to((string)$url);
    }
}

// *********** GOOGLE OAUTH SIGNIN/SIGNUP ********** //

public function loginWithGoogle()
{
    $settings = Setting::first();

    // get data from input
    $code = Input::get('code');

    // get google service
    $googleService = OAuth::consumer('Google');

    // if code is provided get user data and sign in
    if (!empty($code)) {

        // This was a callback request from google, get the token
        $token = $googleService->requestAccessToken($code);

        // Send a request with it
        $result = json_decode($googleService->request('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo'), true);

        $oauth_userid = $result['id'];
        $oauth_username = Custom::slugify($result['name']);
        $oauth_email = isset($result['email']) ? $result['email'] : $oauth_username.'@gmail.com';

        if (isset($oauth_userid) && isset($oauth_username) && isset($oauth_email)) {
            $google_auth = OauthUser::where('oauth_uid', $oauth_userid)->where('service', 'google')->first();

            if (isset($google_auth->id)) {
                $user = User::find($google_auth->user_id);
            } else {
                // Execute Add or Login Oauth User
                $user = User::where('email', $oauth_email)->first();

                if (!isset($user->id)) {
                    $username = $this->createUsernameIfExists($oauth_username);
                    $email = $oauth_email;
                    $password = Hash::make(Custom::slugify('', 12));
                    /*if ($email != $oauth_username.'@gmail.com') {
                        $active = 1;
                    } else {
                        $active = 0;
                    }*/
                    $user = $this->create($username, $email, $password, 1);

                    $new_oauth_user = new OauthUser();
                    $new_oauth_user->user_id = $user->id;
                    $new_oauth_user->service = 'google';
                    $new_oauth_user->oauth_uid = $oauth_userid;
                    $new_oauth_user->save();

                } else {
                    // Redirect and send error message that email already exists. Let them know that they can request to reset password if they do not remember
                    return Redirect::to('/')->with(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => Lang::get('words.username-exists')));
                }
            }
            // Redirect to new User Login;
            Auth::login($user, true);
            return Redirect::to('/')->with(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => Lang::get('words.login-success')));

        }
    } else {
        // get googleService authorization
        $url = $googleService->getAuthorizationUri();

        return Redirect::to((string)$url);
    }
}

/**
 * Signup Signup.
 * POST /signup
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function signup()
{
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), static::$rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $message = $validator->messages()->all()[0];
        return json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => $message));
    }

    $username = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes(Input::get('username')));

    $user = User::where('username', '=', $username)->first();

    if (!$user) {
        $email = Input::get('email');
        $activation_token = str_random(64);
        $user = $this->create($username, $email, Hash::make(Input::get('password')), 0, $activation_token);
        $data = array('username' => $username, 'activation_token' => $activation_token);
        Mail::send(
            'emails.welcome',
            $data,
            function ($message) use ($email) {
                $message->to($email)->subject(Lang::get('words.activation-subject'));
            }
        );

        return json_encode(array('status' => 'success', 'message' => Lang::get('words.register-success')));
    } else {
        return json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => Lang::get('words.username-exists')));
    }
}

private function createUsernameIfExists($username)
{
    $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();

    while (isset($user->id)) {
        $username = $username.Custom::slugify('', 4);
        $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
    }

    return $username;
}

public function activation()
{
    $token = Input::get('token');

    if ($token) {
        $user = User::where('activation_token', $token)->where('active', 0)->first();

        if ($user) {
            $user->activation_token = null;
            $user->active = 1;
            $user->save();

            return Redirect::to('/')->with(array('status' => 'showSuccessToast', 'message'  => Lang::get('words.email-verified')));
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('/')->with(array('status' => 'showErrorToast', 'message'  => Lang::get('words.email-already-verified')));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us the code you've tried so far?

Comment: $table->boolean('admin')->default(0); set to true if added from adminpanel by admin

Comment: you can use their login name and insert it with the other data , just make a session for admin then if isset session x get the name and insert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the controller:

```
If (Auth::check()) && Auth::user()->admin) { 'is admin' ) else { 'is sign in' }
```

Not sure what difference it will make in saving this user but that will be the way to differentiate in your `public function store() {}` UserController.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to do this. The first one is, there is a column in `users` schema:

```
$table->boolean('admin')->default(0);
```

You can use this column as, put the value `1` in case the form is submit by admin, otherwise its default value is `0`.

The another method is, create a column like `created_by` with a default value of `0` for users. Put its value to the logged in `userId`, by this you can identify, by which user the registration is done.